# Cannot use Mac Mail to send email via my two gmail accounts (e.g. iPhotos)

Tags: email

Gmail I cannot configure Apple email on my MacBook Pro to allow me to send iPhotos (for example) via one of my two gmail accounts. I do not normally use Mac mail but I'm stuck with it as part of my software.

One message, for example, claims "Gmail not online" when in fact it is.

I have put in the passwords in both the Account tab and the Advanced tab.

Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, let us try to help you, but please explain bit more what have you done so far.

Comment: How did you setup the Gmail accounts within Mail? There is a wizard-kind-of-thing which guides you through the whole process (and ensures that all the fields and flags are set up correctly), did you use this? And if not, can you please give it a try before we try to dig deeper?

Answer (score 1):

To send photos from within the iPhoto app:

If you get this message in iPhoto when sending email:

[image: password]

Then you need to enter the new/correct password for your gmail (you can find it in your keychain)

To tell it the new password open iPhoto preferences and enter new correct password there.

Here are settings on my mac that work.

[image: iphoto]